# Upstream triggering in Gitlab-CI aka pipeline dependencies

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I can't seem to find the most obvious CI feature that one ever needs from such a tool: run a project pipeline after another project's pipeline has finished. You can do it with `trigger` but only for downstream triggering, which is the opposite of what you want in case you have a project that is a core dependency of 20 other projects which all need to be rebuilt.

What you need in this case is to be able to define something like:

*Project A*: nothing particular, just a normal pipeline

*Project B*, that "depends" on project A:

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
from_upstream:
  stage: pre
  trigger:
    project: ProjectA
```

What it does is trigger ProjectB build whenever a ProjectA pipeline has [successfully] finished.

Instead you must declare all dozens of downstreams in ProjectA in a similar fasion, which is silly and counter-productive, especially when ProjectA is a core library that gets constantly reused everywhere.

So, can someone please explain why GitlabCI is missing an obvious feature (which isn't available even in EE) that has been in Bamboo and Hudson/Jenkins for decades? And how do i do what i need with Gitlab-CI?

UPDATE:
It seems the notion of upstream/downstream is really confusing for some people, so just to clarify: **upstream** *Project A* is and must always be decoupled from **downstream** *Project B* because separation of concern is a thing and upstream maintainers couldn't and shouldn't possibly have any knowledge on how their project is used downstream.

So, desired functionality (which, again, exists for decades in Bamboo and Jenkins) is that downstream pipelines declare passive triggers on upstream pipelines, not the other way around with active triggers as it's currently implemented in Gitlab-CI.

Comment: Well I struggled with the same problem and it was easier to keep CI for multi-project pipelines on Jenkins. So far gitlab-ci seems to be useful only for simple project flows.

Comment: @makozaki Yeah, that indeed seems to be the case

Comment: If you ever find an elegant way to implement this, or GitLab learns to handle such stuff, could you update your question and/or provide an answer?

Answer (score 3):

You can trigger a pipeline in your project whenever a pipeline finishes for a new tag in a different project. This feature was introduced in version 12.8. It is limited to new tags and requires a premium subscription.

- Feature proposal issue: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/9045
- Documentation: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/#trigger-a-pipeline-when-an-upstream-project-is-rebuilt

Comment: "requires a premium subscription" ... oh. Too bad :(

Answer (score 1):

There's documentation and example apps for multi-project pipelines here: https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2018/10/31/use-multiproject-pipelines-with-gitlab-cicd/ and here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/multi-project-pipelines

With the example projects, the project called "simple-maven-dep" triggers the pipeline for the other app ("simple-maven-app") that depends on it.

Comment: Read my question again, it explains that this is the opposite of what i need.

Comment: The problem you stated is solved with the triggers in the links I provided. If you have a library that is used in X projects, and the core library changes, don't the X projects need to be rebuilt to get the changes in the core library?

Comment: Not to mention that your use of curl and Gitlab-CI REST API is absolutely unnecessary, as you can literally trigger another project's pipeline using just its name.

Comment: Did you maybe typo the order of projects you're talking about? If you look at your question, you have this:
"Project A: nothing particular, just a normal pipeline
Project B, that "depends" on project A:
What it does is trigger ProjectB build whenever a ProjectA pipeline has [successfully] finished."

That is exactly what the examples I posted do. ProjectA is "simple-maven-dep" and ProjectB is "simple-maven-app".

Also, the examples are provided by Gitlab. They're not "my use of curl"

Comment: In your case "simple-maven-app" (Project B) depends on "simple-maven-dep" (Project A) and the latter has the trigger. Instead, desirable and intuitive is that the former has the trigger.

Comment: Same problem here, I fully agree with @YogSothoth ...

I have a library and an app. But I don't want to tell the library project to build the app if lib changes (push or downstream principle). I want the app to be build whenever the used library changes (pull or upstream principle). That's exactly the other way around as described above with the example multi project pipline project....

Sadly, it seems this is not possible at all... really bad...

Comment: This link appears to be dead? https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/multi-project-pipelines