# Can I reference another project in a gitlab pipeline instead of cloning it?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am totally new to gitlab pipelines so I'm not really sure what the best way of doing this would be. I've read about submodules and dependencies, triggering other pipelines, but I I'm having a hard time understanding what would help with what I am trying to achieve here.

I have project_b that is a submodule of project_a. In project_b's .gitlab-ci.yml, project_a is currently being cloned, and then project_b is moved to where the submodule normally sits in project_a:

```
...
default:
...
    before_script:
        - git clone (project_a)
        - mv project_a /src
        - rm -rf /src/submodules/project_b/*
        - mount --bind /src/submodules/project_b
...
```

This is because project_b is dependent on project_a.

Though, from what I understand, that means project_b is downstream from project_a.

I don't want to have to clone the whole project_a repo every time that I run the project_b pipeline.

I've seen plenty of info about triggering downstream pipelines for dependent projects, but the only thing I could find that seemed like it related to my case here was this question asked awhile ago about gitlab lacking the feature to trigger an upstream pipeline instead:
[Upstream triggering in Gitlab-CI aka pipeline dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60505357/upstream-triggering-in-gitlab-ci-aka-pipeline-dependencies)

Has this feature been added? Because I sure can't find any info online. Otherwise, any suggestions as to how I could get around cloning the entire project_a repo? I might be totally off here, but one thing I was wondering is if there might be some way that I could have project_b trigger a specific pipeline for project_a that only does what I need it to do to test project_b?

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I'm a bit confused why you say that project_b is dependent on project_a. If b is a submodule of a, I would think a is dependent on b, since a submodule is usually a library or other code that you need to use in the main repository.

Comment: Maybe I could explain better, there are a few different branches of project_a and not all of them require project_b as a component. project_a has some other components like say, project_c. I just want to set up project_b's pipeline to run whats necessary to ensure project_b works correctly, which I need project_a for. Though, I don't want to run project_a's pipeline that does stuff to test project_b, project_c, etc. (Though it seems like I wouldn't be able to do that anyway since I'd be triggering an upstream pipeline)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gitlab CI/CD [multi-project pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/multi_project_pipelines.html) have no intrinsic notions of upstream and downstream, so you can make a pipeline that triggers another pipeline just by referencing the project name in the `trigger` keyword:

```
# inside project B .gitlab-ci.yml

# this stage will trigger project A pipeline to run
merge_requests:
  stage: test
  trigger: my/project_a
```

You can also use the [`rules`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#rules) keyword to run specific stages in the downstream pipeline.

```
# in project A .gitlab-ci.yml

# this will never run when triggered by project B
merge_requests:
  stage: test
  script: echo "test some things"
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "trigger"'
      when: never

# this stage will always run when triggered by project B
merge_request_downstream:
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "trigger"'
  script: echo "test some specific project B things"
```

So you can put your project B specific tests in the script for `merge_request_downstream`. Hopefully that answers your question. I'm not quite sure that's better than just cloning project A in your project B script, but this is how you would accomplish it with multi-project pipelines.